# Rotate shape on a graph

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, geometry

I have some shape built out of points. The coordinates given for each point . (see pic below)[image]

I need to rotate this shape by a particular angle (for example 60° see pic below)
[image]

Is there some formula to achieve this?

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: take the collection of points $(x,y)$ and multiply them by the matrix

$$\left [ \begin {matrix} \cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta} \\ \sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta} \end {matrix} \right ],$$

where $\theta = 60^\circ$, for example.

Comment: @jekcom If you're not familiar with matrices, use the following equations:
$$x_{rotated}=x\cos{\theta}-y\sin{\theta}$$
$$y_{rotated}=x\sin{\theta}+y\cos{\theta}$$

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can. If you multiply by a rotation matrix: $\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin \theta&\cos \theta\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$, where $(x',y')$ are the coordinates after the rotation has been applied and $(x,y)$ are the coordinates before the rotation has been applied . After doing the matrix multiplication, you get $$x'=x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta$$ and $$y'=x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta$$